# Supermarket Simulator using Queue

Tags: java, oop, data-structures, queue

[image]

I posted this problem earlier and i asked for help on how to approach it. I ended up creating a customer class that generates a random first and last name and also assigns random number of grocery items to a customer every time a new customer object is created.

**Here is the code**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Customer {

    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private int groceryItems;

    private String[] last = { "Jordan", "James", "Bryant", "Bird", "Wade",
            "Bosh", "Griffin", "Durant", "WestBrook", "Anthony" };
    private String[] first = { "Michael", "Lebron", "Kobe", "Larry", "Dwayne",
            "Chris", "Blake", "Kevin", "Russell", "Carmelo" };

    public Customer() {
        Random pickLast = new Random();
        lastName = last[pickLast.nextInt(10)];

        Random pickFirst = new Random();
        firstName = first[pickFirst.nextInt(10)];

        Random pickItems = new Random();
        groceryItems = pickItems.nextInt(25);

    }

    public String getlast() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getFirst() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public int getItems() {
        return groceryItems;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("First Name: " + firstName + " Last Name: "
                + lastName + " Items Purchased: " + groceryItems);
    }

}
```

**CODE FOR QUEUE**

```
public class Queue {

    private int maxSize;
    private int[] queArray;
    private int front;
    private int rear;
    private int nItems;

    public Queue(int s) {
        maxSize = s;
        queArray = new int[maxSize];
        front = 0;
        rear = -1;
        nItems = 0;
    }

    public void insert(int j) {
        if (rear == maxSize - 1)
            rear = -1;

        queArray[++rear] = j;
        nItems++;

    }

    public int remove() {
        int removed = queArray[front++];
        if (front == maxSize)
            front = 0;

        nItems--;

        return removed;
    }

    public int peek() {
        return queArray[front];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (nItems == 0);
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return (nItems == maxSize);
    }

    public int size() {
        return nItems;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("First Inserted Item to Last Inserted Item");

        if (rear < front && (!isEmpty())) {
            for (int i = front; i < maxSize; i++) {
                System.out.println(queArray[i]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= rear; i++) {
                System.out.println(queArray[i]);
            }

        }

        else if (front >= rear && (!isEmpty())) {
            for (int i = front; i <= rear; i++) {
                System.out.println(queArray[i]);
            }
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Queue is Empty!");
        }

    }

}
```

Now i was wondering what do i create next? I am just looking for guidance or step by step approach as it will help me learn. Not looking for code. I was thinking that now that i have a customer class i would need to create a Queue that would hold each customer. I know how to write code for a simple int or char queue but i was unclear what the requirements of this particular queue would be , since its holding each customer objects.

Please correct me if i am wrong anywhere in my customer class code and also i would appreciate if someone can provide me steps for the next stage and what i should do .

I am sorry if question is poorly worded as my English is not good and i am certain if i can make this small program working on my own i will have much better understanding of java and Object Oriented programing.

Comment: You need to start completing the queue portion of the question, add the ability to add customers to queues (checkout lanes), and add the ability to remove them from queues, and add the ability to view the status of each queue.

Comment: Yes i thought that is the next thing i needed, just confused as to what kind of queue will i have to make? so far i have only wrote code for making type int queue where i added random numbers. In my case i will be adding customer to the queue so is it a string queue i need?

Comment: You'll most likely want a `Customer` queue.

Comment: I'd suggest making `last` and `first` `static`.

Comment: @user2733436 You probably want a Deque<Customer>, unless you are required to code up your own queue.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove it is asking me to the queue from the earlier chapter , i just posted the code of the queue. I am confused however as the queue is type int so how exactly would i use this queue to store customers? do i change its type?

Comment: @user2733436 It seems like it, but I'd also ask the professor. A problem asking you to store multiple pieces of data in a queue that only stores ints doesn't sound right.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove yeah i am not really doing this for school just self study so i could write my own queue also, i was just following the book instructions which state i can use the queue class we coded earlier

Comment: @NESPowerGlove is it possible to assign each customer some number and insert that number in to the queue class?

Comment: @pjs what type of customer queue would i create? since my queue class only accepts int type do i need to create a new one?

Comment: You can create an array of anything, so since you're using an array to back your queue implementation you should consider making it an array of what you need - customers. If you want to be more flexible, consider using generics and specifying the type of data to be used when you instantiate the queue.

Answer (score 2):

Now you should add different lineups of people(To simulate different checkout lines). So what I'd do is create an Queue for each checkout line you want. Then, as the problem states, when a key is pressed, it creates a new customer. The customer needs to figure out which line to go to, so maybe assign it to the one with the least amount of total items (or total people if you want to make it easier), and prefers the on closest to, say the left, in the case of more than one shortest queue. Then you need to make the customer buy their items and then leave. If you decide you want to do it at a button press, as the problem suggests, you can set it up so that every time that button is pressed, you call a method in each of the customers (only the ones at the start of the line, with array index 0) that decreases their items by one, and deletes the customer object from the Queue when it reaches zero, to simulate them leaving and another customer taking its place. Now you need to show these things to the user somehow. Perhaps just a simple "[Customer Name] Joined this line. Current line ups are: Line 1: 2 people Line 2: 5 people" etc, and a "[Customer Name] left this line after buying their groceries."

I hope that this is what you wanted, and I hope it helps.

Comment: it is asking me to the queue from the earlier chapter , i just posted the code of the queue. I am confused however as the queue is type int so how exactly would i use this queue to store customers? do i change its type?

Comment: @user2733436 I'm sorry, I thought you were using the Queue from the Java API. You could maybe assign each customer a specific number, and use that.

Comment: That might be a neat trick around this issue, can you elaborate?

Comment: @user2733436 somewhere in the Customer class, create a public int, which should be unique for every customer (Increment by one each time you create a customer). Then you can use that number in the Queue, and whenever you need to get something from the Customer class, you can go through your Customer objects (stored in an ArrayList maybe?) and find the neccesary one. It's by no means an elegant way of doing things, but if you want to use the Queue class, I think this would be a good way to do it.

Comment: I think i would have to create the unique number int outside the customer class right? if i create it inside the customer  class it will not work. I appreciate your explanation i am still not sure how to add the customers in a queue using this approach...

Comment: @user2733436 You create one int outside of the class, say, in your main class, and every time you create a Customer, you give it that number, then increment the number in the main class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

class CirQueue {
    private
        int max,rear,front;
        int[] a;
        int size;
    
    public
        CirQueue(int m) {
          max = m;
          size = 0;
          a = new int[m];
          rear = front = -1;
        }
    
        void insert(int val) {
            if(isFull()) {
                System.out.println("CUSTOMER CANNOT BE ADDED AS QUEUE IS FULL");
            } else {
                if(isEmpty()) {
                    front = rear = 0;
                    a[rear] = val;
                } else {
                    rear = (rear+1)%max;
                    a[rear] = val;
                }
                size++;
            }
        }

        int size() {
            return size;
        }

        void decFront(int rmv) {
            a[front]-=rmv;
            if (a[front] <= 0) {
                delete();
            }
        }
        
        void display() {
            if(!isEmpty()) {
                int i;
                for(i=front; i!=rear; i=(i+1)%max) {
                    System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
                }
                System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        boolean isFull() {
            if(front == (rear+1)%max) return true;
            else return false;
        }

        boolean isEmpty() {
            if(size == 0)  return true;
            else return false;
        }

        int delete() {
            if(isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Underflow");
                return -1;
            } else {
                int temp = a[front];
                if(rear==front) {
                    rear = -1;
                    front = -1;
                } else {
                    front = (front+1)%max;
                }
                size--;
                return temp;            }
        }
}
```